# Using while loop to count amount of inputs. C

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, eof

As the beginning of my program, I am using a `do-while` loop to count how many inputs a user enters. The `do-while` loop should end after `EOF` (Ctrl+D) is input. 
My problem is however, that when I enter 1 value and then press Ctrl+D, my program says it has counted two inputs, when I want it to be only one.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
   int n=0;

printf("Enter values.\n");

do {
    n++;
   }
while (EOF!=scanf("%d",&n));


printf("%d\n",n);

}
```

If I compile the program and run it, and enter a 1, then press enter, and enter Ctrl+D, it says `n=2`. Why is this? I only entered 1 value.

Comment: Because it is do..while loop.
`n++` will be executed before Ctrl+D is read. Easiest solution, change to **while** loop

Answer (score 2):

1. `n++` is executed. `n` becomes 1.
2. `scanf("%d",&n)` is executed. The input `1` is read.
3. `n++` is executed. `n` becomes 2.
4. `scanf("%d",&n)` is executed. It returns `EOF` and break from the loop.

As a result, the result becomes 2. I think you should `while` statement instead of `do` statement in this case. Also, do not break the counter with `scanf()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int n=0, m;

    printf("Enter values.\n");

    while (1==scanf("%d", &m))
    {
        n++;
    }

    printf("%d\n",n);

    return 0;
}
```